# Preprint by Wall on Sjogren's theorem

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, paper-request

In their account http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049(87)90048-X of Sjogren's theorem, Cliff and Hartley refer to two articles:

[9] B. Hartley, A note on a lemma of Sjogren relating to. dimension subgroups, Research Report 229, Department of Mathematics, National University of Singapore, 1985.

[21] G.E. Wall, to appear. (!)

I am especially interested in the second reference, but no article by G.E. Wall from that period seems to match the (somewhat terse) citation.

Does someone have a scanned copy of these prepublications? Many thanks in advance

Comment: Did ever appear a copy of B.Hartley's Singapore write-up on "lemma of Sjogren"? It could be posted or made available on the Web. I had it at one time, received directly from Prof. Hartley. Many thanks !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The paper you are looking for seems to be

G. E. Wall: *Dependence of Lie relators for Burnside varieties*, Groups—Canberra 1989
Lecture Notes in Mathematics Volume **1456** (1990) pp 191-197.

In particular, I think that the relation with the article you are reading is at page 193 (but Wall's construction looks much more general).

It is actually possible to find Wall's paper on the web. If you do not find it, contact me and I will send you a copy by email.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had looked at his 1993 papers, but missed that one.

Comment: Wall's paper is short (and the volume exists in many libraries), but the standard Springer link online gives only the first two pages: http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0100741#page-1

Comment: You are right. I meant some "unofficial" repositories. Unfortunately, I cannot post the link here without violating the copyright  :-)